# Codeigniter 2.0 MY_Router.php error

Tags: codeigniter-2, php

I created the file `MY_Router.php` inside the core directory with this code:

```
<?php
class MY_Router extends CI_Router {

    function MY_Router()
    {
        parent::CI_Router();
    }

    function _validate_request($segments)
    {
        // Comprueba que el controlador no existe
        if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$segments[0].EXT))
        {
            $segments = array("page", "load", $segments[0]);

        }
        return parent::_validate_request($segments);
    }
}
?>
```

When I call the application, this error appears:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Router::CI_Router() in /home/david/public_html/CodeIgniter_2.1.0/application/core/MY_Router.php on line 6

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that there is no method in the CI_Router class called `CI_Router()`.  In PHP4, constructors have the same name as the class.  In PHP5, constructors are named `__construct()`.

To fix the issue, change the constructor in the MY_Router class from

```
function MY_Router()
{
    parent::CI_Router();
}
```

to

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```